# How does session expiration work?

Tags: support, logout, openid

How does session expiration work on Stack Overflow? Is it independent of the OpenID provider? Does expiration take place regardless of when you last visited a site?

I'm asking because every once in a while (weeks/months) I seem to lose my session for no apparent reason, most recently less than an hour ago. I was logged in earlier this morning, and suddenly while browsing questions I notice I'm no longer logged in. I'm using Stack Exchange OpenID and Firefox (latest version).

Comment: Same happens to me every once in a while, but I've blamed Safari's/OS X's keychain so far, didn't occur to me that it could be caused by SO

Comment: It might be that one of the cookies needed for authentication don't slide for some reason. The `acct` cookie does slide for me but the `sgt` cookie doesn't and given that the last one has an expiration for me in november it could be that I get logged out in November.

Comment: I remember being logged out suddenly once because I switched wireless networks (and therefore IP addresses). Of course, they do that for security purposes.