# Why do I get logged out every few days?

Tags: bug, login

On multiple browsers (Safari, Chrome), and multiple operating systems, Stack Overflow only keeps me logged in for a few days. This is quite frustrating as it means I need to keep logging in. I've had this experience for a few years. This seems like a bug?

My `acct` session cookie has an expiration date of 2017-05-19, so it shouldn't be expiring any time soon.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334029/how-does-session-expiration-work